# MacOs SwiftUi Strange behavior when focusing on TextField

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, focus, textfield

[image: Swift]

How can you see in the image this happens?
Can you tell me the reason?

```swift
@State var accountName = ""

 HStack {
        Text("Account:")
        TextField("Enter your username", text: $accountName)
                        .frame(width: 300)
}
```

Comment: This is a known bug https://twitter.com/krzyzanowskim/status/1471841667950993408?s=21&t=5AaJPX72-NM84jtiQuL7Kw it’s actually getting worse

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.2.1. Which env did you use? Do you have some additional modifiers to that TextField?

Comment: Xcode 13.3.1 / macOS 12.3, The code is simply that.

Comment: @Asperi: The sembra problem will happen when you use a dialog.